# Serialize on a PC, deserialize on an android phone?

Tags: java, android, serialization

Is it possible to serialize an object on a pc, send it through a socketed connection to an android phone and then deserialize it and use it on the phone?
I read somewhere that there might be an issue with the JVM version but didnt fully understand what the issue might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rely on a fact that JSON should handle this stuff at standard level, not in library implementation

Comment: Look at the GSON library so you can turn your objects to/from JSON in a single line http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: Do I need to use a server for that? at the moment I just want to send things through a socket over tcp/ip without the need for a server. i.e. no http.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, it's no problem. Think about applet... 
Byte codes could be transported via net and then be executed by remote client jvm. However, JVM has different implementation following some specification (***JSR). As a result, it's possible that some codes run into problem in different jvm.